# jQuery UI (iPod Like Menu) has a confliction with jQuery UI AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-menu

Has anyone run into any problems running jQuery UI AutoComplete and jQuery UI iPod like DrillDown Menu?

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Menu

I realize it's still in a development stage, but curious if anyone else has noted this issue?
If you know of a fix that would be awesome as well.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the jQuery UI iPod like drilldown menu to have a new function name and it worked great.

Comment: @Justin can you elaborate, post some code perhaps I'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem - renaming works:

in fg.menu.js find (right on top after comments)

```
var allUIMenus = [];
$.fn.menu = function (options) {
```

and replace "menu" eg. with "ipodmenu" like

```
var allUIMenus = [];
$.fn.ipodmenu = function (options) {
```

now you call your menu within your pages like

```
$('#flyout').ipodmenu({
        content: $('#flyout').next().html(),
        flyOut: true 
    });
```