# Conflict between jquery ui widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, conflict

I'm using **ipod style menu with breadcrumb** from this page http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

and

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox at the same time.
Now the problem is they're conflicting. Ipod style menu with breadcrumb works well but combobox doesn't. The combobox giving bunch of errors. I suggest both using same var names. Is there any way to fix that problem?

Comment: What are those errors, exactly? Does the combobox work if you remove the breadcrumb widget?

Comment: yep. it works without ipod menu well.

Comment: @Juhanna are you still there?

Comment: See my answer at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380189/jquery-ui-ipod-like-menu-has-a-confliction-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete/17064819#17064819

Answer (score 1):

Are yo using both for the same or for different?If different it works well as I have just implemented here you can go through this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/r8tHu/15/

Answer (score 0):

Dosen't the new jQuery UI Menu do the same as the Ipod Menu?

You can try using this instead, since it is both official widgets from the jQuery UI team:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Menu

Could you paste the errors you get?